# Spring + ElasticSearch - How to bulk create or update document with autogenerated string _id/id

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

currently, we are forcing the _id of the elastic search documents by setting the id field. This simplifies the design, as it allows to perform updates and/or creation of new documents without previously knowing whether a document is already present in the index.

For example, this is the class representing the document:

```
@Data
@Document(indexName = "person")
public class Person {

  @Id
  private String id;
  
  private String name;
}
```

and this is the method for bulk create or update:

```
 public void bulkCreateOrUpdate(final List<Person> personList) {

    List<UpdateQuery> updateList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Person person : personList) {
      UpdateQuery updateQuery = UpdateQuery.builder(person.getId())
          .withDocument(this.operations.getElasticsearchConverter().mapObject(person))
          .withDocAsUpsert(true)
          .build();
      updateList.add(updateQuery);
    }

    this.operations.bulkUpdate(updateList,
        this.operations.getIndexCoordinatesFor(this.entityClass));
  }
```

When saved, this is what it produces:

```
  {
    "_index": "person",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "10001",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "_class": "com.app.Person",
        "id": "10001",
        "name": "Miguelito",
    }
```

How/what to modify the code so that the _id is autogenerated during saving? Is there an annotation that can be used on id field or is there a need to modify the bulkCreateOrUpdate implementation? The expected output is this:

```
  {
        "_index": "person",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "qwrqwr3242frw",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
            "_class": "com.app.Person",
            "name": "Miguelito",
        }
```

Please advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate Id as the string then use generator="uuid" as follows

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String id;

private String name;
```

try it and let me know

Comment: How about on the bulkCreateOrUpdate method? Will there be any changes when creating the UpdateQuery (passing the id on the builder)?

Comment: probably not... because while using the update query it will take the row's id which you want to update. just be careful while writing the query.

Comment: can you also provide how can I create/ initial insert when id==null?